# How do I find and remove any rule or newline in an output?

Tags: c#, xml, string, newline

I have written an app to compare the response I get for a request with its standard response. If they differ I need to find the difference. Since the response I get for the request has \r and \n in between it doesn't match with the standard response even though the responses are the same.How do I remove these \r and \n which are in the response string I get? Please advice.

```
<R>
<T>Expired</T>
<K>Service</K>
<E></E>
<S>0,license
</S>
</R>
```

Comment: @CodeCaster Replace method doesn't help. Please give another solution

Comment: "doesn't help" doesn't help. Please provide example input and output, show your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: I have added the XML. In there since there is \r\n at the end of S tag, the regular expression I used considers from <R> to <license> as one string and </R></S> as another string. The regular expression I used is (?:\\s*\\<R.*</R>\\s*) Please help.